# Pushing into an array with OOP js

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, frontend

The array:

```
var cake = {
    selectors : {
        '.this-is-a-class' : {
            type:'color'
        }
    }
};
```

The push:

```
cake.push({
    selectors: {
        '.cake-in-orlando' : {
            color : 'red'
        }
    }
});
```

The error:

**Uncaught TypeError: cake.push is not a function**

Comment: There is no array in your code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You should explain what it is you are trying and also perhaps google what you can call push on. e.g. an Object is not a thing you can call push on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as others have mentioned, your variable does not contain an array.  It contains an object with nested objects.  `{}` is object syntax in javascript.  `[]` is array syntax in javascript, when defining a variable value.

Since you have not updated your question to clarify which way you want this to go, to be a real array or to use the object as is, I'll provide a version of both.

### Array Version

This version uses a real array, containing the object with the selector key and a value of a sub object with the key of type and value of color

```js
var cake = [
    {
        '.this-is-a-class' : {
            type:'color'
        }
    }
];

cake.push({
    '.cake-in-orlando' : {
        color : 'red'
    }
});

console.log(cake);
```

### Object Version

This version uses the original object, and adds the new "selector" to the existing "selectors" sub object.

```js
var cake = {
    selectors : {
        '.this-is-a-class' : {
            type:'color'
        }
    }
};


cake.selectors['.cake-in-orlando'] = { color : 'red' };

console.log( cake );
```